# Does Razor Pages sit over the MVC layer?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

In the latest open source .NET framework (5 or 6), for web application development there are two templates:

1. MVC - 3 files - model/view/controller
2. Razor Pages - 2 files - view/code-behind

For new development it is recommended to use Razor Pages.

Both the above are separate concepts. So why does the architecture diagram show MVC as base layer for Razor Pages?

Shouldn't Razor Pages have been placed next to the MVC? Or does it truly sit on top of the MVC layer?

Source: https://youtu.be/d9Bjg31VuHw at 44:12

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Razor Pages is dependent on parts of the MVC framework, like attribute routing, model binding and action results, which is why it is considered a layer on top of MVC. You can't avoid adding `using` directives for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` in a Razor Pages application.

Comment: I'm confused because razor pages doesn't have model view controller or does it? All I know is that mvc and razor pages are 2 separate project templates.

Comment: In Razor Pages, the PageModel is the Controller and the cshtml file is the View. The model in Razor Pages and MVC is basically everything else.